# New array on heap causing "malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)" error

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

Background:
I'm porting a piece of software from a PowerPC processor driven platform to a RaspberryPI4. The device run by the program is a kind of proxy between another device and a server that collects data provided. Problem was that a lot of communication was done by memcpy'ing from and to TCP, serial and file buffers. I've written a bunch of "LEMEMCPY" functions that handle the buffers correctly by now, so i think this is not a real problem (but might be anyway, that's why I'm noticing this).

Problem:
There is a structure that contains an array of another structures. Sizes of them all are determined in runtime, so everything is made on the heap. Now, everything was good until we loaded a new config file (good one, it works on the "before-port" machine).
There is a "for" loop, that loads the config, here's how it looks (a "bit" simplified):

```
struct Str1
{
    int i;
}

struct Str2
{ 
    byte size;
    Str1* strs1
}
for(...)
{
    Str2 strs2; <== it's an attribute of another structure in outer for
     ...setting "size" here, evaluates to 1 in the failing case
    strs2.strs1 = new Str1[size]; //<==== here it fails
    setting_the_attributes_here();
}
```

The last part is in a nested for loop, and is running correctly for 301 times (of total 320) and then throws `malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)`.
There are no "handmade" `mallocs` nor frees, only `new`s, and the `delete` part of code is not even reached at this moment. I've been through lots of posts, but there was always problem with writing to or freeing freed memory, it's not the case this time.
Thanks in advance for any help and clues.

=====

EDIT

Well, the thing is too complex to rework it to a shareable form and I am not permitted to share it as is. Thank you and sorry for taking your time. When i get to the answer with my team i'll try to explain what the problem was. If this thread is a rubbish, please delete it.

Comment: The error you get is typically because you do something somewhere in your code that writes out of bounds of the allocated memory. Do you remember to allocate space for the null-terminator, for example?

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the error.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way, while porting the code why not refactor it to be a little more modern? Like for example use `std::string` for strings? Or `std::vector` for other arbitrary data?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude time matters here to run it as soon as possible, the app is being rewritten but for now i need to launch it "now"

Comment: I'll edit the question providing some real code

Comment: @Piotrek -- The code you've added doesn't tell us when, where, or how that code is called.

Comment: Now for the good news: If you run Linux on the RPi, you can use e.g. [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org) to debug such errors. Build with debug information, run in the Valgrind memory checker, and it will tell you exactly when and where you do things like go out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, valgrind just became a new friend ;) it's going to be a looong night

Comment: This screams memory corruption to me.  Get your code working with asan (hopefully your cross-compiler supports it) or run it in valgrind.

Comment: try compiling code with the flag -fsanitize=address